# Cannot build any WEBGL project on Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to build any of my projects using WebGL platform Unity gives me multiple errors. Re-installation and changing the year of the unity didn't help. WebGL platform gives me errors even when I try to build completely new project:

```
BuildFailedException: Incremental Player build failed!
UnityEditor.Modules.BeeBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at <42a64fd733d9417da1ea3a757ad9a96d>:0)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:179)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <42a64fd733d9417da1ea3a757ad9a96d>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <42a64fd733d9417da1ea3a757ad9a96d>:0)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()



UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 5 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <42a64fd733d9417da1ea3a757ad9a96d>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <42a64fd733d9417da1ea3a757ad9a96d>:0 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun ()


[Version and Build] Build failed! 00:00:27.5054735
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Unity.Play.Publisher.Editor.PublisherBuildProcessor/<WaitUntilBuildFinishes>d__7:MoveNext () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.connect.share@4.2.3/Editor/PublisherBuildProcessor.cs:77)
Unity.EditorCoroutines.Editor.EditorCoroutine/YieldProcessor:MoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.editorcoroutines@1.0.0/Editor/EditorCoroutine.cs:80)
Unity.EditorCoroutines.Editor.EditorCoroutine:ProcessIEnumeratorRecursive (System.Collections.IEnumerator) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.editorcoroutines@1.0.0/Editor/EditorCoroutine.cs:134)
Unity.EditorCoroutines.Editor.EditorCoroutine:MoveNext () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.editorcoroutines@1.0.0/Editor/EditorCoroutine.cs:115)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

I tried reinstall unity, change its version, change preferences but nothing helped.

Comment: what version of unity - ive built webgl on so many .. no issue, and as its bitching about editor coroutines do you need them?

Comment: @BugFinder 2022.2.15. f1. Editor coroutines? You mean coroutines I used in the scripts?

Comment: no, editor coroutines - its a package.. read the errors :P